# Facebook Graph User Locations change

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Recently I've been building an application that uses the Facebook graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/locations/)

I've recently realised that the locations it has been grabbing both in my application, and in the Graph explorer have been missing lots of locations I have been tagged in.

I use to be able to retrieve over 500 locations (multiple pages) from Facebook, now I'm receiving less than 500 (single page). This is both in my application and in the explorer ([https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Flocations%3Flimit%3D500](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/locations?limit=500))

If anyone has any ideas that would be great - this is for my final year developmental project at university.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the graph api a access token to receive a users locations

Answer (score 0):

I think if you've the following permissions you'll get all the locations of the user-

> - `user_photos`
> - `user_status`
> - `friend_photos`
> - `friend_status`

You can check what all permissions your access token is carrying in [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/locations/)